# Getting list of all columns corresponding to maximum value in each row in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

How to get list of all columns corresponding to maximum value in each row in a Dataframe?
For example, if I have this dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,34,98,26],'b':[12,87,98,12],'c':[11,23,43,1]})

    a   b   c
0  12  12  11
1  34  87  23
2  98  98  43
3  26  12   1
```

I want to make another dataframe as shown below,

```
0  [a,b] 
1  [b] 
2  [a,b]
3  [a]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try these codes (bot approaches do the same):

```py
max_cols_df = pd.DataFrame({"max_cols": [list(df[df==mv].iloc[i].dropna().index) for i, mv in enumerate(df.max(axis=1))]})
max_cols_df = pd.DataFrame({"max_cols": [list(df.iloc[i][v].index) for i, v in df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).iterrows()]})

max_cols_df 
----------------
    max_cols
0   [a, b]
1   [b]
2   [a, b]
3   [a]
----------------
```

But I think you asked a related question to another post and cannot upgrade `pandas`. Therefore, the second could throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using **Pandas Melt**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,34,98,26],'b':[12,87,98,12],'c':[11,23,43,1]})

df = df.reset_index()

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'],value_vars=['a','b','c'], var_name='col_name')

df['Index_Value_Max'] = df.groupby(['index'])['value'].transform('max')

df[df['value'] == df['Index_Value_Max']].groupby(['index']).agg({'col_name':'unique'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, get the max value in each row:

```py
df.max(axis=1)
```

Then check the dataframe for values that equal max values.

```py
df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Then apply a function row-wise to select for the column names where the value in the row is `True`.

```
df.apply(
    lambda row: [k for k, v in row.iteritems() if v], 
    axis=1
)
```

Summarily, this is:

```py
df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).apply(
    lambda row: [k for k, v in row.iteritems() if v], 
    axis=1
)
```

```
0    [a, b]
1       [b]
2    [a, b]
3       [a]
dtype: object
```